# Javascript BlackJack script not executing/calling "hitMe()" and "stand()" function with buttons in Mozilla Firefox in a new document

Tags: javascript, blackjack, hit

**Note:** This code works on ALL the browsers BESIDES Firefox, and yes, I'm using the latest version.

**Note:** Im only including the code that is having issues, everything else works fine.

When I programmed the code below, Firefox would load everything else just fine.

The browser would accept the first button-function (a function called by a button), but not accept the 2nd or 3rd button-function.

The "Deal" button not included in the code I am presenting to you works fine. It prints a new page.

Now when the new page is printed, the "Hit" and "Stand" buttons appear. The problem is...

...the buttons will not print a new page like the "Deal" button did.

I belive the problem is either the defining of the function(s), or the content inside of them.

```
//**** STAND FUNCTION START DEALS DEALER CARDS ****
function stand()
/*Altough we have a "printCards" function, we will print the cards
differently in the stand function. Why? When the first cards are printed,
we have a hidden one, thus showing the hidden card in this function*/
{
dealerAcesTotal = dealerTotal;
if (dealerAcesTotal == 22){(dealerAcesTotal = 12);}

//KEEP DEALING CARDS TO THE DEALER WHILE THE HAND IS UNDER 17
while (dealerAcesTotal < 17)
{
randA = Math.floor((Math.random()*52)+1);//for the dealer
dealerCards[dealerHits] = card[randA];
dealerTotal = (dealerTotal + dealerCards[dealerHits][3]);
if (dealerCards[dealerHits][3] == 11){dealerAces = (dealerAces + 1);}
dealerHits = (dealerHits + 1);
dealerAcesTotal = dealerTotal;
}
//end of KEEP DEALING CARDS TO THE DEALER



//add a new row for totals and DEAL button
document.write("</TR><TR><TD align=center><FONT color=white><kbd>Dealer = " +     dealerAcesTotal + "</TD>");
document.write("<TD align=center><FONT color=white><kbd>Player = " + playerAcesTotal +     "</TD>");
document.write("<TD align=center><FONT color=white><kbd>BET = $" + bet + "</TD>");
document.write("<TD align=center><FONT color=white><kbd>" + handText + "<BR>"+ name    +"'s&nbsp;Bank: $" + currentBank + "</TD>");
document.write("<TD align=center><FONT color=white><kbd><button onclick=\"\dealCards    \(\)\">Deal</button></TD>");
document.write("</TR><TR>");
//****END OF PRINT CARDS TO FINISH HAND SCREEN
document.close();
return;
}
//**END OF STAND FUNCTION**

function hitMe(){playerHit();} //a sort of test for the browser...
//****PLAYER HITS FOR A NEW CARD****
function playerHit()
{
randA = Math.floor((Math.random()*52)+1);//for the player
playerCards[playerHits] = card[randA];
playerTotal = (playerTotal + playerCards[playerHits][3]);
if (playerCards[playerHits][3] == 11){playerAces = (playerAces + 1);}
playerHits = (playerHits + 1);
playerAcesTotal = playerTotal;
// run a loop for as many aces in the hand
//if the playerTotal is over 21 deduc
for (i = 0; i< playerAces; i++)
{
if ( playerAcesTotal > 21){playerAcesTotal = (playerAcesTotal - 10);}
}
printCards();
//document.close();
//return;
}
```

Feedback would be REALLY appreciated. :)

PS: My script is on the current page: http://ca1k.xkotto.com/portfolio/BLACKJACKV10.html

Comment: The problem can be fixed by clearing the cache.  try it out maybe?

Comment: Im sorry, I have tried that solution and no progress so far, but thank you for your effort to help me.

Comment: just check this out https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/751899

Comment: If you execute document.write any time after the page has loaded you will clear the page.

Comment: My JavaScript works completely fine. I am just confused by what kind of error breaks the functions...

Comment: Try rewriting it with DOM functions instead of `document.write()`.

Comment: What is the difference? I don't see anything changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hitme and stand wont work in firefox because those functions are undefined when you call them.

- Go to your page in Firefox, right click and choose view source. See all your code?
- Now, click deal. When the page changes, right click and choose view source again. See how all your javascript code has disappeared?

This is because your `printCards()` (and really all of your functions) incorrectly use `document.write`. Other browsers like chrome are forgiving and will let you get away with this but in firefox when you do this you are overwriting the information that was previously on the page (including the javascript code itself).

You'll need to change all of your `document.write` usages to use DOM functions instead like `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += '<td>My New Card</td>'`

and your `document.clear` would be `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML ='';`

Your probably going to have to tweak your styling to work with these changes also.